# Computer will not boot at all, even into BIOS

Tags: boot, motherboard, hardware-failure, desktop-computer, post

I asked a question a few months ago about my computer randomly shutting down, but not powering off, i.e. the fans were running but no input was taken and the screen didn't come on. It happened again today, and now I can't turn my computer on at all. I hit the power button, and the fans spool up like normal, but nothing happens. No USB power, no nothing. The one thing that is really odd is that the silent mode and stop lights on my graphics card (I have a Gigabyte Windforce GV-R938G1 GAMING-4GD) will flicker twice about every 17 seconds. They also do this on startup, just without repeating. This leads me to believe that it is a boot loop, but I don't know how to break the loop and I don't know what could be causing it, or even if that is what's happening. I have tried power cycling, leaving it off for a while, leaving it unplugged for a while, and unplugging the reset switch in case of a short. This is my own, custom-built computer. Specs below, any help much appreciated.

AMD FX-6320 6 cores @ stock speed
AMD R9 380 4 GB
2×4 GB DDR3 Corsair Vengeance Blue
EVGA SuperNOVA 750 G2 750 W PSU
WD Black 1 TB 
Gigabyte GA-970A-D3P
Running latest Windows 10 (Upgrade version)

Update 01/29/2017

Just got my board back from RMA at Gigabyte (after well over a month) and it still does not work. While it was gone, I tested my power supply with a multimeter and got essentially perfect readings from the CPU, GPU, and motherboard cables. I also got a speaker to listen to the POST codes and there is nothing. No beeps. I have no idea what this could be.

Answer (score 1):

Unplug all your cords and hit the power button for 10 seconds to drain any remaining power , next is remove all your RAMs and try to boot without the RAMs if it successfully boots then start adding RAMs one by one to check which one is faulty sometimes removing your CMOS battery and resetting your bios would do the trick but I recommend that you take a look for any flashing LED lights on your case cause sometimes they indicate what's the issue with your PC if so, please check the manufacturer diagnostics with LED lights to explain what's going on with your PC .

Comment: Removing the RAM did not fix the situation. I suppose that means the RAM is clear of problems, though. I am a bit leery of resetting the BIOS, as that seems like more of a last resort kind of solution. As an update, I took all of my components out of the case to make sure short-circuiting is not an issue. No significant change occurred. Meaning that this is a problem with any of the motherboard, GPU, CPU, and power supply. Unfortunately, I don't have a speaker to listen to the POST beeps. Should I spring for one just to fix this problem?

Comment: You don't have to listen to POST beeps you can just look at them flashing or maybe in your case you have to hear them .so you tried removing rams what about other devices like VGA and LAN ? Also your HDD try removing everything and adding it back just to make sure where the problem lies just out of curiosity did you happen to leave it on for like 5 minutes? Cause my PC once took 5 minutes to boot each time I turned it on to bios screen it's due cause it needed a bios update and if removing all the hardware fails I think your last resort would be resetting the bios before thinking of CPU and MB

Comment: There is no way for me to tell if the computer is on without the graphics card in. Otherwise, there is no indication that it isn't, plus I can't get a video signal without it to show that it is on

Comment: Nothing happened when I removed the graphics card, RAM, HDD, and optical drive. This is down to the power supply, motherboard, and CPU. The support company for the PSU told me it was a motherboard problem. The support company for my motherboard tells me there is no problem. Is this is a CPU problem? And if so, what are the implications of that? I.e. data loss, multiple component failure, etc., and can it be fixed?